# PHP Trace Redirect

Tags: php

I have a database of over 10,000 URL's, however every single one of them redirects to another URL. How can I request a URL and find out it's final destination in a path of (possibly) multiple redirects?

Comment: Could you share "that option"? I'm interested...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using the [cURL](http://php.net/curl) functions:

```
$c = curl_init('http://original.url');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($c);

// Error checking here - see curl_error()

$newUrl = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

curl_close($c);
```

Comment: You might also want to do `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,$n);` where $n is some reasonable number that would prevent following an unreasonalble number of redirects for a given url.

Comment: As it is now it returns and displays the page being queried, how can I do it silently?

Comment: $c is missing in curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
Its should be,
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);