# How to follow a URL redirect to the final location?

Tags: php, redirect

How can I get the **final destination URL** for an Airbnb short-link URL in PHP? (e.g. https://abnb.me/Vt3MA7vVyM)

Using [Redirect Detective](http://redirectdetective.com/), I can see that the link gets redirected three times:
[image: redirect results from redirect detective]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Trace Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587578/php-trace-redirect)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the solution of _"PHP Trace Redirect"_ don't give the correct URL.

Comment: @Syscall yeah because js redirects are not handled in curl afaik

Comment: Right @MehravishTemkar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` follows the redirections defined in the HTTP response. But, there is a redirection in JavaScript using `window.top.location`. So, you can parse it using `strpos()` and a simple `preg_match()`:

```
$url = 'https://abnb.me/Vt3MA7vVyM';
$ret = file_get_contents($url);
$pos = strpos($ret, 'window.top.location');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $str = substr($ret, $pos);
    $str = preg_match('~validate\("([^"]*)~', $str, $matches);
    echo html_entity_decode($matches[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
 https://airbnb.com/rooms/2110908?=&s=41&ref_device_id=43fb193006d0cb8848f689aec67ba15ae5c48471&user_id=10758532&_branch_match_id=519823851281523702
```